# How to bundle single angular spec file?

Tags: angular, testing, jestjs

The question might be a bit weird, but the requirement I have seems also quite weird.

Please don't ask why, but I need to be able to package single angular jest (with `jest-angular-preset`) spec file as a bundle (without an access to the sources), which can be run with node and to test the specific functionality.

Is there any reasonable way to compile a single spec file with all the jest / angular dependencies into a node runnable bundle?